# How do I connect a switch and receptacle in the same box?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have extended wire at the end of an existing circuit. I’m installing a 2-gang box with a switch and a receptacle. I want one of the outlets to always be hot, and the other to only be hot when the switch is on. How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]
<sup>*In this image the top outlet is controlled by the switch, while the bottom is always hot*</sup>

- Using a crimp cap (or other approved means), connect two bits of bare or green wire to the incoming bare/green wire. *If this is a metal box, use three bits of wire, and attach one to the box using an approved grounding screw.*
- Attach one bare/green wire to each device.
- Connect the incoming white (grounded "neutral") wire to one of the silver colored screws on the receptacle.
- Break the tab on the side of the receptacle, between the brass colored screws.
- Using a twist-on wire connector (or other approved method), connect two bits of black wire to the incoming black (ungrounded "hot") wire.
- Connect one black wire from the bundle to the switch.
- Connect the other black wire from the bundle to one of the brass colored screws on the receptacle.
- Connect a bit of wire from the remaining screw on the switch, to the remaining brass screw on the receptacle.